# Minimization of linear combination of vectors

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra, vector

Suppose I have a vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{6}$. For example, take the vector $v = k(-2,2,4,6,2,2)$. I would like to find some $k$ with the constraint that the last two components are necessarily non-negative and that every component in the vector is a minimal integer. For example, in this case, I would take $k = \frac{1}{2}$. Is there a way to implement such a minimization procedure in mathematica given an arbitrary six-component vector?

In particular, suppose I have now $n$ such vectors with $n \lt 6$. Is there a way to find the linear combination of such vectors with minimal integer entries and with the same constraint that the last two components are non-negative?

I've thought about trying to use Reduce or Solve, but I was wondering if there's some faster way to implement this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about what you want, but perhaps:

```
f[v_] := v Sign[v[[-1]]]/GCD @@ v 

v0 = {-2, 2, 4, 6, 2, 2};
f@v0
(*  {-1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1} *)
```

Comment: @user238194 Have you tried to generalize it?